# Getting error in file_get_content() function

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get data from the following JSON file using PHP. My json data is

> {"ERROR":0,"STATUS":2,"ORDERID":15245611,"OPTRANSID":"","PARTNERREQID":"9876543299","MESSAGE":"Success","USERVAR1":"","USERVAR2":"","USERVAR3":"","COMMISSION":"0.2000"}

I wrote the code as :

```
$data = "http://url.php"
$obj = json_decode(file_get_content($data),true);
echo $obj['STATUS'];
```

But the I am not getting output of it.

Please help me how can i get the STATUS from the URL.

I am getting an error as

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_content()

Can you help me what i am doing wrong on this. Thank You

Comment: The error code told you already exactly what your problem is. Googling it would have help you. Asking it here was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this my way to get value from json, hope this can help you

```
$json = json_decode($response,true);
echo $json['STATUS'];
```

Answer (score 3):

There is typo mistake in your code use:

`file_get_contents()` instead of `file_get_content()`

Answer (score 1):

function name is worng
from

```
file_get_content
```

to

```
file_get_contents
```

Comment: Now i am getting an error 'failed to open stream: No such file or directory'

Comment: can you paste url here??

Comment: Sorry inside that i have lacks of balance.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the function: Try this

```
$data = "http://url.php"
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($data),true);
echo $obj['STATUS'];
```

Comment: I am getting same problem...'failed to open stream: No such file or directory'

Comment: it means that URL which you are using is not proper. Could you provide the URL which u r hitting?